# suddenly I'm getting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is not defined when using runserver

Tags: python, django

The full error is:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'app.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
```

The whole time,

```
python manage.py runserver
```

had been working fine, and `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` was never defined previously - that is not the issue here, since I'm running `manage.py` which should set this itself.

The problem occured after I added some imports - runserver immediately stopped working.   I also can't do validate - nothing works.  Setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` doesn't help, either, although that's what the error is suggesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding toplevel imports of internal django functions can break django in really non-obvious ways.

```
from django.core import context_processors
```

was in a file that was imported into settings.py pretty early, which caused this error.

In my opinion, django could use a better way to detect this type of problem.  The line which caused the problem didn't show up in the traceback at all.