# Python 2.7 suddenly not working: "Symbol not found: __PyErr_ReplaceException" when I try django runserver

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

## Problem

I didn't knowingly make any significant changes, but suddenly, when I try to run my django app locally, I get the following error:

```
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ foreman start
03:55:28 web.1  | started with pid 38101
03:55:29 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
03:55:29 web.1  |   File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/bin/gunicorn", line 5, in <module>
03:55:29 web.1  |     from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
03:55:29 web.1  |   File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 22, in <module>
03:55:29 web.1  |     import zipfile
03:55:29 web.1  |   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
03:55:29 web.1  |     import io
03:55:29 web.1  |   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
03:55:29 web.1  |     import _io
03:55:29 web.1  | ImportError: dlopen(/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyErr_ReplaceException
03:55:29 web.1  |   Referenced from: /Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
03:55:29 web.1  |   Expected in: flat namespace
03:55:29 web.1  |  in /Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
03:55:29 web.1  | exited with code 1
03:55:29 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$
```

That `foreman start` command is how I always run the app locally (based on heroku instructions), instead of `python manage.py runserver` (so I don't know if `python manage.py runserver` was even working at all recently) but now the error messages (above) are the same for both `foreman start` and `python manage.py runserver` anyway.

I also get the same error even if I revert back to a much earlier git commit, a commit for which `foreman start` worked at the time, so I don't think it's a new line added recently to my code. Rather it seems something's changed about the way python is set up (if that's possible?)

## Additional info

This all happened as suddenly as described in [31164285](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164285/emacs-python-jedi-suddenly-failing)

I always run the project in a virtual environment as you can see from (awe01) in brackets

```
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ which python
/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/bin/python
```

Based on this thread ([31106958](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106958/importerror-symbol-not-found-pyerr-replaceexception#comment50229050_31106958)), the following output might be informative to somebody?

```
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ nm /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python | grep PyErr_ReplaceException
0000000000092b82 T __PyErr_ReplaceException
```

Note that if, in this venv, I type "python", it tells me I'm using 2.7.6

```
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/feedparser-5.1.2-py2.7.egg', '/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python27.zip', '/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7', '/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/Extras/lib/python', '/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Output of `brew config`

```
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ brew config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
HEAD: 02d219b58d254c0e8bd77a73d901b0e03af13818
Last commit: 5 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https://homebrew.bintray.com
CPU: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.10.5-x86_64
Xcode: 6.3.2
CLT: N/A
Clang: 6.1 build 602
X11: N/A
System Ruby: 2.0.0-p481
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby
Java: 1.8.0_40
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$
```

Output of `brew doctor`

```
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/node/ares.h
    /usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
    /usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_internals.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
    /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/ngx-queue.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/stdint-msvc2008.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/tree.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-bsd.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-darwin.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-linux.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-sunos.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-unix.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-win.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-preparser.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8stdint.h
    /usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
    /usr/local/include/node/zlib.h

Warning: Your Xcode (6.3.2) is outdated
Please update to Xcode 6.4.
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

Warning: Some keg-only formula are linked into the Cellar.
Linking a keg-only formula, such as gettext, into the cellar with
`brew link <formula>` will cause other formulae to detect them during
the `./configure` step. This may cause problems when compiling those
other formulae.

Binaries provided by keg-only formulae may override system binaries
with other strange results.

You may wish to `brew unlink` these brews:

    openssl
```

The command `python manage.py shell` fails with the same error, but when I jump into the python console directly I can see what imports work or don't work
(This thread recommended checking urllib2)

```
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ python 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 80, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyErr_ReplaceException
  Referenced from: /Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

## Attempts so far (no luck yet)

### 1. Re-install python

That was recommended here: https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/508
and on question [31900156](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900156/python-suddenly-has-error-no-module-named-unittest-im-not-running-a-unit-te)

So I ran the following:

```
brew uninstall python
brew update 
brew install python
```

It didn't solve the issue.

This tells me it's not a django or app-specific issue; it's a python problem. 
Here's the output after uninstalling and re-installing python; I get the same error for running `pip` command:

```
 (awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ brew uninstall python
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2... (6194 files, 96M)
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ brew install python
==> Downloading https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/Python-2.7.10.tgz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/python-2.7.10.tgz
==> Downloading https://bugs.python.org/file30805/issue10910-workaround.txt
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/python--patch-c075353337f9ff3ccf8091693d278782fcdff62c113245d8de43c5c7acc57daf.txt
==> Patching
patching file Include/pyport.h
Hunk #1 succeeded at 713 (offset 14 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 736 (offset 14 lines).
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2 --enable-ipv6 --datarootdir=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/share --datadir=/usr/local/Cellar/python/
==> make
==> make install PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2
==> make frameworkinstallextras PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/share/python
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-18.0.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/python--setuptools-18.0.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-7.1.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/python--pip-7.1.0.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/w/wheel/wheel-0.24.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/python--wheel-0.24.0.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.txt --
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.txt --
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.txt --
==> Caveats
Pip and setuptools have been installed. To update them
  pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

You can install Python packages with
  pip install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

See: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Homebrew-and-Python.md

.app bundles were installed.
Run `brew linkapps python` to symlink these to /Applications.
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2: 6194 files, 96M, built in 3.4 minutes
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ pip install --upgrade
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import io
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyErr_ReplaceException
  Referenced from: /Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ brew linkapps python
Linking /usr/local/opt/python/IDLE.app to /Applications.
Linking /usr/local/opt/python/Python Launcher.app to /Applications.
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ pip install --upgrade
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import io
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyErr_ReplaceException
  Referenced from: /Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$
```

The reason I checked urllib2 specifically was based on [this comment on
issue-1384](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1384#issuecomment-106696085)

Note at this point the python installed is version `2.7.10_2` but when I just type `python` in the virtual env awe01 it still brings me to a shell where version is 2.7.6

```
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

### 2. Trying foreman start outside of virtual env

This means that python is the system python, 2.7.10

```
MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

This also fails, but I get a different error message

```
MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ foreman start
04:44:30 web.1  | started with pid 50330
04:44:30 web.1  | /usr/local/foreman/bin/foreman-runner: line 41: exec: gunicorn: not found
04:44:30 web.1  | exited with code 127
04:44:30 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$
```

Interestingly now, that `foreman start` error differs to this `python manage.py runserver` error:

```
MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 98, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'shareducate.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named dj_database_url
MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$
```

In other words, my problem now looks just like question [10812651](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813651/suddenly-im-getting-django-settings-module-is-not-defined-when-using-runserver), "suddenly I'm getting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is not defined when using runserver". Response to that question blamed `context_processors`, but I've made no deliberate adjustments to `context_processors`.

Note that while `python manage.py shell` still fails, if I just type `python` I can use the python shell... and the version is `2.7.10` now (not 2.7.6 as in venv above). 
Also note in case urllib2 is relevant (and yes, this is used in my code also), now I CAN import it without any error:

```
MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>>
```

The output:
    MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ nm /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python | grep PyErr_ReplaceException
    0000000000092b82 T __PyErr_ReplaceException
is exactly the same as when run inside the virtual env.

### 3. openssl

Hence why `brew doctor` shows a special note on openssl above: I had tried the following 3 lines of code from question [31888394](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31888394/870121)

```
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
brew install python
```

(I think the openssl line of investigation follows from the urllib2 checking above)

Seems to have made no difference.

### 4. Attempt downgrade from 2.7.10 to 2.7.9

Not sure if this would make a difference since the venv seems to be 2.7.6 anyway, but when I do try [as recommended on github ([issue-1367](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1367) and [issue-1384](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1384) and in question [31888479](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31888479/870121))
`brew switch python 2.7.9` I get error,

```
Error: python does not have a version "2.7.9" in the Cellar.
Versions available: 2.7.10_2
```

[EDIT: Steps 5-7 added based on comments]

### EDIT: 5. Check/amend PATH

Advice such as[23783054](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27383515/870121) and [issue-40241](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/40241) suggested amending PATH. 
I ran this single command from [5846204](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5846204/870121):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Since the whole setup was working and then suddenly stopped working, I'm reluctant to make too many system changes that might complicate the picture...

### EDIT: 6. virtualenv --clear [following @Maikflow's comment]

Resulted in this error

```
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:heroku macuser$ deactivate
MoriartyMacBookAir13:heroku macuser$ virtualenv --clear awe01
Deleting tree awe01/lib/python2.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 824, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 984, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1145, in install_python
    rmtree(lib_dir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 508, in rmtree
    shutil.rmtree(dir)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'awe01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mutagen-1.22-py2.7.egg-info/dependency_links.txt'
MoriartyMacBookAir13:heroku macuser$
```

## EDIT: Success

### 7. Create a new virtualenv with the system's python 2.7.10

[Following @Evert's comment]

```
(awe01)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awe01 macuser$ deactivate
MoriartyMacBookAir13:awe01 macuser$ cd ..
MoriartyMacBookAir13:heroku macuser$ virtualenv awe02 --no-site-packages
New python executable in awe02/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
MoriartyMacBookAir13:heroku macuser$ cd awe02
MoriartyMacBookAir13:awe02 macuser$ source bin/activate
(awe02)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awe02 macuser$
```

At this point I copied the app folder, awesomeapp to be inside the folder awe02 (alongside bin, lib and include folders)

```
(awe02)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awe02 macuser$ cd awesomeapp/
(awe02)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

When I did `pip install -r requirements.txt` I got a bunch of errors for psycopg2 
`warning: unused function 'Dprintf'` and 
`warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int'`
 but right before I gave up programming for ever, I tried 
`foreman start`
and it works!

```
(awe02)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ foreman start
16:28:16 web.1  | started with pid 14174
16:28:16 web.1  | 2015-08-22 16:28:16 [14174] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.0.0
16:28:16 web.1  | 2015-08-22 16:28:16 [14174] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (14174)
16:28:16 web.1  | 2015-08-22 16:28:16 [14174] [INFO] Using worker: sync
16:28:16 web.1  | 2015-08-22 16:28:16 [14177] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14177
```

This is python 2.7.10

```
(awe02)MoriartyMacBookAir13:awesomeapp macuser$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import urllib2
>>>
```

Similarly `python manage.py runserver` works as well :)

## Other thoughts

I think I have updated OS X to version 10.10.5 since the last time `foreman start` was working. Is it possible the system updated some core files?

## Thanks

I am still teaching myself python/django so there are some gaps in my knowledge... Any trouble-shooting approaches or tips would be massively appreciated.

Comment: restart the virtualenv:
`virtualenv --clear venv`

restart it with the no-site-packages flag and see how that goes.

Comment: I haven't read through all details, but it appears when you start Python outside the venv, you pick up the homebrew Python. Depite your `which python` output saying `/usr/bin/python`; the default OS X system Python is at version 2.7.6 for me. Or did you try and upgrade the system Python?

Comment: Try to create a new venv with the homebrew Python; there's usually a `--python=...` option where you can point to `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. @Maikflow, Evert, I don't know what python I had before (maybe 2.7.6?), but `brew install python` means I have 2.7.10 now.
Combining both your suggestions, a new venv with `--no-site-packages` worked! I edited answer, your suggestion is step 7. I will do more investigating then edit this question to better explain path to success. Still many questions remain for me as I don't really understand what's happened. Glad to be able to run server locally though!

Comment: @Mark It happened to me once when i copied an app from root to another user's directory, after hours i finally got it to work by restarting the virtualenv like i said above. Glad i could help :).

Answer (score 0):

[Maikflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3505811/maikflow)'s solution worked for me:

> Restart the virtualenv: `virtualenv --clear venv`